# Fabric Channel questions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

A couple of questions on channel:

- Characteristics of a channel:

besides partition does the channel have the characteristic of hierarchy - meaning, if I have 3 channels can I arrange them into a hierarchy structure, channel a contains channel b and channel b contains c?

- Management of channel:

sort of related to above question; 
what is the best practice to manage all channels under one peer/user,such as, CRUD? In my mind this concept of channel seems to be a great idea but could possibly become out of control quickly - the impact on scalability, performance, storage and data segregation of the network. 
Is there any details around the roadmap of how to manage the channel in both the micro and macro sense?

Answer (score 1):

These are Hyperledger Fabric questions, as Composer does not manage channels (you deploy a Composer business network archive TO an existing channel).

Channels are essentially separate ledgers. They allow you to manage a single Fabric, that supports multiple ledgers across different subsets of your peers.

Comment: is correct. There is no hierarchical relationship of channels. They are independent of one another. There is discussion of adding a new version of Hyperledger Explorer from a member company that is being actively discussed. I believe it will allow one to interact with channel creation/management.

Comment: Thx Chris. Do we have any timeline on this? Cheers!